# Android: Send byte array in JSON using POST

Tags: android, json, arrays, http-post

I have a JSON server (WCF REST) with a JSON POST method that accepts an object containing id (string) and an image (byte[]):

```
    [DataContract(Name = "image")]
public class CustomImage
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "imagestream")]
    public byte[] ImageStream { get; set; }
}
```

I have managed to send data to the server from an C# console application with the following code:`      byte[] bytearray = null;

```
        Stream stream = File.OpenRead(@"c:\temp\snow.jpg");
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        bytearray = new byte[stream.Length];
        int count = 0;
        while (count < stream.Length)
        {
            bytearray[count++] = Convert.ToByte(stream.ReadByte());
        }

        CustomImage image = new CustomImage {Id = "43"};
        image.ImageStream = bytearray;
        WebClient Proxy1 = new WebClient();

        Proxy1.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializerToUpload = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof (CustomImage));
        serializerToUpload.WriteObject(ms, image);
        byte[] data = Proxy1.UploadData("http://localhost:5465/MyService/file/post", "POST", ms.ToArray());`
```

But I am not able to get this to work in my Android-application. I am using the following code:`    public boolean UploadImage(String id, byte[] imageData) throws JSONException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        BasicHttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = getHttpClient();

```
    HttpResponse response = null;
    HttpPost httpost = null;

    String url = String.format("file/post");
    url = String.format("%s/%s", API_ROOT, url);

    httpost = new HttpPost(url);

    //JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();      
    //for(int i=0;i<imageData.length;i++) {
    //    jsonArray.put(imageData[i]);
    //}

    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    data.put("id", id);
    data.put("imagestream", imageData);
    data.put("imagestream", jsonArray);


    StringEntity se = null;
    se = new StringEntity(data.toString());

    httpost.setEntity(se);

    response = null;
    httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    try {

        response = httpClient.execute(httpost, localContext);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // System.out.println("HTTPHelp : ClientProtocolException : " +
        // e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // System.out.println("HTTPHelp : IOException : " + e);
    }

    if (response != null && response.getStatusLine() != null
            && response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But all I am getting is:

`The request body could not be deserialized. End element imageStream from namespace '' expected. Found text '[B@406bb748'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your image. Maybe it needs to be Base64 encoded before being submitted.

Comment: Ok i got it. But should i have to post String instead of that byte[] ?

Comment: Ok i have passed it as string in the json object and it works fine.